# how to remove an element inside a cursor in android without recreating the cursor?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a cursor example that populate listview with txt example

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

what i want to know is there a way to filter inside the cursor remove some element
at runtime without recreating the cursor?

something like if cursor contains letter c then remove it from the cursor, is it posible?

Comment: if you are removing from database and wanting to just request a new cursor. There's Cursor.requery() which has been deprecated and it says "Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back." Furthermore you can implement ContentProvider which automates this.

Comment: what i want to do is get all video from a folder then put it in a cursor, is there a way to directly filter the elements and remove elements which is equals example "c" or its always nesecary to fitch the value of the cursor first and recreate a new cursor?

because i want to use simplecursoradapter, not baseadapter.

Comment: Tell me more about why do you want to remove that element from the cursor?

Comment: i have a sharedpref that save title of the video from favorite,
so if that title is favorite, then in favorite tab only the title that is favorite is displayed in the listview, and im using simplecursoradapter to populate my listview data, what i want is is there a way to remove a cursor element?